# Get difference of digit count between 2 numbers

Tags: java

For a simple command line tool I want to draw a simple graph showing some points and their y-axis value. For the y-axis labeling I want to print the level of the current "row" like:

```
55,09|  |
54,90|  ||
54,70|  ||
54,51|  ||
54,32|  ||
54,13|  ||
53,94|  ||
53,75|  ||
53,56|  ||
53,37|  |||
53,18|  |||                   |    |
52,99|  |||            |     ||    |
52,80|  |||         |  |     ||    |
52,61|  |||         || |     |||   |
52,42| ||||||       || |  |  ||||  ||
52,23| ||||||       ||||  |  ||||  ||
52,04| ||||||       ||||  |  |||| |||
51,85| ||||||       ||||  |  |||| |||
51,66| ||||||       |||| ||| |||| |||
51,47| ||||||      ||||||||| ||||||||
51,28| ||||||      ||||||||||||||||||
51,09| ||||||      ||||||||||||||||||
50,90| ||||||     |||||||||||||||||||
50,71| ||||||     |||||||||||||||||||
50,52| |||||||    |||||||||||||||||||
50,33| |||||||    |||||||||||||||||||
50,14| |||||||  |||||||||||||||||||||
49,95| |||||||  |||||||||||||||||||||
49,76| |||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||
49,28| ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

but it can happen that the max value has more digits than the min value:

```
1000,00| |
666,67| | |
333,33| |||
0,01|||||
```

so how can I get the difference of the digits between the max and min value so I can add leading spaces?

```
1000,00| |
 666,67| | |
 333,33| |||
   0,01|||||
```

Comment: use `String.format()`, or `System.out.format()` and a pattern like `%7.2f` for a number, where `7` denotes width of a number, `2` denotes width of decimal part.

Comment: Given that your data is in order, why not just pad everything to the same length as the highest value?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou for `%7.2f` 7 is a min width and will pad with spaces, otherwise go over 7 depending on the number

Comment: @flkes yes, you're right. OP may chose another witdh according to their actual values. `7` is just an example (enough for `1000.00`)

Comment: I would try to prefix all numbers with zeros up to the highest number, to line up. (to avoid leading spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty:

```
double max = getMaximum(); // Get your maximum Y value
int smax = String.format("%.2f", max).length(); // Print as a string and get number of characters
```

In your loop:

```
System.out.format("%"+smax+".2f", value);
```

---

**Edit, from @EJP's comment**

It is indeed both cleaner and more efficient to use `log10` on the max. It will give you the power of 10, hence the number of digit (minus one) that will be used. While the first solution is straightforward (counting characters, which is straightly what we want), that solution is better in every other aspect:

```
double max = getMaximum();
int ndigits = (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(max)) + 1;
int precision = 2; // Number of digits after decimal point
String fmt = "%"+(ndigits+1+precision)+"."+precision+"f"; // "%x.pf", x is the TOTAL length, including the point and precision digits
```

In your loop:

```
System.out.format(fmt, value);
```

Comment: Taking the floor of the log10 would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @EJP Indeed, though I think you meant ceiling+1 so that ceil(log10(1000.0))=4. I'll update my answer when I get a compiler to test it properly.

Comment: No. What I really mean is floor(log10))+1, or ceil(log10)). What you've suggested here is still wrong. It gives 2 digits for 9, and 3 for 11.

Comment: Ha you're right! I didn't noticed the first space in my test... Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @EJP I'd go for floor()+1 instead of ceil(), as it gives the correct value (4) for 1000, when ceil() gives 3.
Does your downvote still hold?